# How to display a specific value from a database as the first drop-down list selection option

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I have an application which takes in user data, saves it to a database, and then allows users to edit that data. I have one variable which is populated using a drop-down list. When users go to edit data, I would like their selection from the database to show at the top of the drop-down list. For example, if they created a new user (Jane Smith) for company "CoolCompany" and is now editing Jane Smith, I'd like it to show "CoolCompany" as the first drop-down list selection. Currently it's showing the list in alphabetical order ("AwesomeCompany"). I suspect this is because of the way my AddUserForm is set up. Can I adjust that in my view? We have enough companies listed that it needs to stay alphabetical when users add data.

Models:

```
from location import db
from location.folders.models import Company

class ProductUsers(db.Model):
    __table__ = db.Model.metadata.tables['product_users']
  
    company = db.relationship('Company', foreign_keys='ProductUsers.prod_id')

    def __init__(self, first_nm, last_nm, prod_id):

        self.first_nm = first_nm
        self.last_nm = last_nm
        self.prod_id = prod_id

    def get_id(self):
        return int(self.prod_user_key)
```

Forms:

```
from location.otherfolders.models import ProductUsers
from location.folders.models import Company

class AddUsersForm(FlaskForm):
    company = SelectField(
        'Company*', 
        validators=[DataRequired()],
        choices=[(comp.prod_id, comp.comp_display_name) for comp in Company.query.filter(Company.member_status!=500).order_by('comp_display_name').all()])
    first_nm = StringField('First Name*', validators=[DataRequired()])
    last_nm = StringField('Last Name*', validators=[DataRequired()])
   
    submit = SubmitField('Submit User')

class UpdateProductUserForm(AddUsersForm):
    first_nm = StringField('First Name*', validators=[DataRequired()])
    last_nm = StringField('Last Name*', validators=[DataRequired()])

    disable = SubmitField('Deactivate')
```

Views to update user:

```
from location.otherfolders.models import ProductUsers
from location.folders.models import Company

from location.otherfolders.forms import AddUsersForm, UpdateProductUserForm

approvals = Blueprint('approvals', __name__)

@approvals.route('/productapproval/addproductUser/<int:prod_user_key>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit_product_users(prod_user_key):
    
    productUser = ProductUsers.query.get_or_404(prod_user_key)

    form = UpdateProductUserForm()

    if form.validate_on_submit():

        productUser = ProductUsers.query.filter_by(prod_user_key=prod_user_key).first()

        productUser.org_id = form.company.data
        productUser.first_nm = form.first_nm.data
        productUser.last_nm = form.last_nm.data
   
        db.session.commit()

        flash('User Account Updated', 'success')

        return redirect(url_for('approvals.users', prod_user_key=prod_user_key))

    form.company.data = productUser.prod_id
    form.first_nm.data = productUser.first_nm
    form.last_nm.data = productUser.last_nm


    return render_template('/productapproval/addusers.html', form=form)
```

Template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block form_content %}

<form class="form form-horizontal" method="POST">

  {{ form.hidden_tag() }}

  <div class="form-group row">
    {{ form.company.label(class="col-sm-3 col-form-label font-weight-bold") }}
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      {{ form.company(class="listStyleComp") }}
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    {{ form.first_nm.label(class="col-sm-3 col-form-label font-weight-bold") }}
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      {{ form.first_nm(class="form-control sm-text listStyleComp", placeholder="First Name") }}
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group row">
    {{ form.last_nm.label(class="col-sm-3 col-form-label font-weight-bold") }}
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      {{ form.last_nm(class="form-control sm-text listStyleComp", placeholder="Last Name") }}
    </div>
  </div>

<!-- BUTTONS -->
 <div class="form-group row">
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-success") }}
  </div>
</div>

</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you are missing the `company` field from your `UpdateProductUserForm`.

Add that in there:

```py
class UpdateProductUserForm(AddUsersForm):
    first_nm = StringField('First Name*', validators=[DataRequired()])
    last_nm = StringField('Last Name*', validators=[DataRequired()])
    company = SelectField('Company*', validators=[DataRequired()], choices=[])
    disable = SubmitField('Deactivate')
```

Notice that we define it as an empty list. Then we update it however we want in the view:

```py
@approvals.route('/productapproval/addproductUser/<int:prod_user_key>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def edit_product_users(prod_user_key):
    
    productUser = ProductUsers.query.get_or_404(prod_user_key)

    # get all the companies
    companies = [comp.prod_id for comp in Company.query.filter(Company.member_status!=500).all()]
 
    # move current company item to start of list
    current_company_index = companies.index(productUser.prod_id)
    companies.insert(0, companies.pop(current_company_index))

    form = UpdateProductUserForm()
    form.company.choices = companies
    form.first_nm.data = productUser.first_nm
    form.last_nm.data = productUser.last_nm

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        productUser.org_id = form.company.data
        productUser.first_nm = form.first_nm.data
        productUser.last_nm = form.last_nm.data

        db.session.add(productUser)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('User Account Updated', 'success')

        return redirect(url_for('approvals.users', prod_user_key=prod_user_key))

    return render_template('/productapproval/addusers.html', form=form)
```

I noticed you were fetching the user twice. You don't need to do that. Also you weren't properly adding the updated user to the database session. I've fixed those things in the above code.